# how do json data become dynamic html tables using php?

Tags: php, html, json

how the json key is used as the table name, and displays data in the table, without the table name being created

```
{
   "status": "sukses",
   "title": "OK",
   "img": "ok.jpg",
    "data": {
    "network": {
        "technology": "No cellular connectivity",
        "2g_bands": " N\/A",
        "gprs": "No",
        "edge": "No"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to make it like this

```
statuss title img     technology               2g_bands gprs edge
sukses  ok    ok.jpg  No cellular connectivity N\/A     No    No
```

with php Below, I am confused how to retrieve the json key to retrieve the name of the table I need to be dynamic

```
<?php
$Libs = new Library();
$result = $Libs->pilihmodel($idbrand,$idmodel);
if ($result->rowCount()>0) {
    while ($datas = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $datass = $datas->jsondetail;
        $hasiljson =  json_decode($datass, TRUE);
        $binatang = array($hasiljson);
        echo "<table>";
        foreach ($binatang as $jenis) {
            foreach ($jenis as $nama) {
                echo "<td>$nama</td>";
            }

        }
      echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't show the PHP code which creates the tables, we cannot tell you how it's  being done in this particular case.

Comment: Or are you asking how you would write such code? It's not clear. The way you've written it suggests you might want us to look at some existing code. I cannot tell.

Comment: @ADyson, sorry I forgot the location of the php code

Comment: ok thanks. Well all that this PHP code does is output some basic data, with `<br>` for new lines. have you at least _tried_ to generate a HTML table instead? Also, how many rows of data does your SQL query return?

Comment: @ADyson, I have created a table with html, but I want the table name to be taken from the json key

Comment: "I have created a table with html"...please show how you did it then. I don't see any `<table>` or `<tr>` or `<td>` tags in your code right now.

Comment: just read the desired fields from the json and create the table as you want and as it should be based on the incoming json , i assume you have problem in writing the code to do this

Comment: I've made the table above, sorry I bother you @ADyson

Answer (score 0):

You're about halfway there. Getting the keys is easy in a PHP `foreach` loop using `$key => $value`) syntax. Then you can, in parallel, build the header row and data row using the key and value from each field. Because of the structure of the JSON you also need to make a special case for the "data" object.

*(If the structure is unpredictable you could make a recursive function which would traverse the structure and either print a field if it's a plain string, or find its children if it's another array, but that's probably overkill for what you're doing here. If you really need that though, please mention it.)*

This will work:

```
$hasiljson =  json_decode($datass, TRUE);
$header = "";
$body = "";

foreach ($hasiljson as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key != "data")
    {
        $header .= "<td>$key</td>";
        $body .= "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($hasiljson["data"]["network"] as $key1 => $value1)
        {
            $header .= "<td>$key1</td>";
            $body .= "<td>$value1</td>";
        }
    }
}
echo "<table><tr>$header</tr><tr>$body</tr></table>";
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b61f2933b0ebf8a3ea1091c1e4474882e8c90a1